# Can't install jenkins (AKA hudson) slave on windows

Tags: hudson, jenkins, slave

i have followed the instructions:
first, you need to start Jenkins before installing it.(i did that on the server itself from command line by running "java -jar jenkins.war".)

Now connect to Jenkins by going to the following URL http://:8080/
Once Jenkins is started this way, look for the "Install as Windows Service" link in the "Manage Jenkins" page (requires .net framework version >= 2.0): 
i don't have any install as windows service link in the manage jenkins page. 
anyone?
please?

Comment: What version of Windows, and what version of jenkins are you using?

Comment: Managed to install but now i get ststus code 500 when installing as a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Tomcat to host your jenkins instance? Tomcat runs fine as a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest windows installer, it does the service setup automatically. Double check services.msc.

Answer (score 0):

In "Hudson", since a commit over a year ago,that option is disabled from the JLNP file.
See commit:
https://eclipse.googlesource.com/hudson/org.eclipse.hudson.core/+/c326860072d4c339c6eae34826132b2150753f1a%5E%21/

According to the commit message, service installation of the Slave Agent is broken, and hence it has been disabled. (disclaimer: I have not tested if this is true for me or not yet).

This probably doesn't apply to the original question, as the question pre-dates the commit, but it may well apply to any other people who like myself are facing the issue currently.

Raul